# DataGridView DataSource Not Updating

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datatable, devexpress

I am using Winforms DevExpress  and I am binding a DataTable to a DataGridView which is working fine. The problem I am having is that I have some functions that will build a new DataTable object which is separate from the original which needs to replace the original DataTable that is bound to the DataGridView.

```
DataTable originalTable = new DataTable("OriginalTable");

//Populate originalTable 

myDataGridControl.DataSource = originalTable;
```

Everything works fine with the code above, but the following code creates a new DataTable and needs to be set as the DataSource for myDataGridControl.

```
DataTable newTable = new DataTable("NewTable");

//Populate newTable

//Set newTable as the DataSource for myDataGridControl
myDataGridControl.DataSource = newTable;
```

I have tried several different attempts to make this work such as calling RefreshDataSource(), Refresh(), setting DataSource to null. I have not gotten it to work yet. How do I do this?

Comment: winforms...sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 9):

Try using a `BindingSource`, like this:

```
DataTable sourceTable = new DataTable("OriginalTable");
BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = sourceTable;
myDataGridControl.Datasource = source;
```

Now when you want to re-bind, update the `sourceTable` variable, like this:

```
sourceTable = new DataTable("NewTable");

// If the structure of `OriginalTable` and `NewTable` are the same, then do this:
source.ResetBindings(false);

// If the structure of `OriginalTable` and `NewTable` are different, then do this:
source.ResetBindinds(true);
```

Note: Read [BindingSource.ResetBindings Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings.aspx) for more information about `ResetBindings()`.

Comment: I tried this exactly, and it doesn't seem to be working. Not sure why this would not work.

Comment: This seems to be updating the rows, but the columns are not updating. I have verified that the columns are in fact in the sourceTable, but they are not showing the change on the grid control.

Answer (score 7):

Having you tried the following combination?:

```
myDataGridControl.DataSource = originalTable;
myDataGridControl.DataSource = null;
myDataGridControl.DataSource = newTable;
```

In my experience, setting the `DataSource` to `null` then to the second source does the trick.

Comment: This is actually the first attempt I tried at making it work, but it did not change it unfortunately. This has worked for me in the past as well.

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody is having trouble even after trying the other suggestions, the following call to PopulateColumns() on the GridControl.MainView property solved the problem for me.

For example:

```
myDataGridControl.MainView.PopulateColumns();
```

This can also be referenced from the following article with DevExpress. http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q362978

Answer (score 0):

Kinda old topic, but since it bugged me, I decided to share my experience...
Binding the source didn't work for me and Datagridview doesn't have "MainView" variable.

I suspect the issue happens, in my case, after running the sorting command:

```
MyDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Column Asc";
MyDataTable = MyDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

My solution was to rebind again after actions performed:

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = MyDataTable;
```